# How to create a simple Java form with Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm very new to swing and have trouble dealing with `JFrame`s so I thought you guys could help.

I'm trying to make a simple window show up with 3 text fields and a check box. At the bottom there should be a "done" button which closes the form.

I can make the `JFrame` with the `JTextField`s and `JCheckBox` but how do I retrieve the input?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`.  Anything that ends *"At the bottom there should be a "done" button which closes the form"* strongly suggests a dialog to me.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), you can add an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`, which will be called when the button has been pressed.

To retrieve the text from the `JTextField`, use the [`JTextField#getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) method

To determine whether the `JCheckBox` is actually selected, use the [`JCheckBox#isSelected()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) method

But a good starting point is reading the [Swing tutorial from the start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the checkbox input? Is there any way to get it as a boolean? I literally just learned how to make checkboxes and know nothing about them

Comment: @MeshulamSilk I just updated my answer, as I saw I missed the `JCheckBox`

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out that link to find out how to add an actionlistener to the button and i should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you would post some code showing how you show your `JFrame`, then I could give you a more specific example.

In general, you'll have a class that extends `JFrame`, `JDialog`, etc. In that class you'll have getters and setters that will get and set the values of the controls on the form.

In your case, once "Done" is clicked you could have a listener, either on the "Done" button or on the frame itself (listening for the closing event) retrieve the values from your form and do something with them.

If this isn't clear please post some code and perhaps I can give you a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private JButton doneBtn = new JButton("Done");

    // rest of your form
}
```

If you want to get the contents of `textField` when the `doneBtn` is pressed, you need to attach an *event listener* 
to the button:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private JButton doneBtn = new JButton("Done");

    public MyFrame() {
        // Here we attach an event listener to the button.
        // Whenever you press the button, the code inside actionPerformed will be executed
        doneBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println(textField.getText()); // Or do whatever you like
            }
        });
    }

    // rest of your form
}
```

But, honestly, you should learn this yourself. If you haven't read a tutorial about check boxes, of course you won't know how they work. Read first, and if you had a question, then ask for help. You haven't read enough and yet you are asking questions.

Comment: I actually did look around but I couldn't find a clear enough explanation that left me knowing what to do. I knew I could find a good answer from willing-to-help people on here so here I came and I got my answer. Thanks for the help and sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: You are welcome and no you didn't waste my time. But this is explained in all the Swing books I've seen.

Comment: Ah... Well I'm still in school and I'm making a game (involving this form) as a side project for extra points. We're not required to know Swing by the ministry of education to pass computer sciences so the only place to learn about it is the internet (English java books are hard to come by here).
Next time I'm out of the country I'll make sure to buy some sort of book. Any suggestions?